Difference between How do I .... How could I... and How would I? Link two verbs with "and" or "to"?


How do I not strive hard and give it a try?




How do I not strive hard to give it a try?




How could I not strive hard to give it a try?




How would I not strive hard to give it a try?


Wiht these 4 sentences what are differences in their meanings?
Which one is suitable for introduction given by an applicant during a job interview?

(3) means the speaker is saying he wouldn’t be able to refuse to attempt.  This is the most suitable answer.
In (4), the speaker is saying it is unlikely that he wouldn’t try hard.  This option lacks the sense of helplessness expressed in (3) and is hence not as strong a statement.
(1) and (2) aren’t suitable.  They have a sense of the speaker asking for ways to refuse to strive hard. Although context rules out this interpretation by the interviewers, it's not great.  This point aside, strive and give are more closely linked in (2).
